# Button should display new text under half, but lets headline and image "jump"

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem. I have a heading with an image and a button below it.
If you press this button, another text should appear.

The problem is that when I press the button, the text appears but the heading and the image "jump", i.e. they change their position. I would like the heading and image to stay where they are and only the text to be added at the bottom.

I am using Boostrap.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import photo from './somepng.png'

const Test = () => {

    const textBlockRef = useRef(null);
    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

    const openPopup = () => {
        setShowPopup(true);
    };

    const closePopup = () => {
        setShowPopup(false);
    };


    React.useEffect(() => {


        const body = document.querySelector("#hearts-container");

        const createHeart = () => {
            const heart = document.createElement("div");
            heart.className = "fas fa-heart";
            heart.style.left = `${Math.random() * 100}vw`;
            heart.style.animationDuration = `${Math.random() * 3 + 2}s`;
            body.appendChild(heart);
        };

        const removeOldHearts = () => {
            const heartArr = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-heart");
            if (heartArr.length > 200) {
                heartArr[0].remove();
            }
        };

        const heartInterval = setInterval(createHeart, 100);
        const removeInterval = setInterval(removeOldHearts, 100);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(heartInterval);
            clearInterval(removeInterval);
        };
    },
        []);

    return ([
        <div id="hearts-container"></div>,
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                <h1 className="header_text">Heading</h1>
                <div className="gif_container mt-3">
                    <img src={photo} alt="image" className="img-fluid" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={openPopup} style={{ marginTop: '40px' }}>Нажми на меня</button>
        </div>,
        <div className="text">
            
            {showPopup && (
                <div className="popup">
                    <div className="text_block" ref={textBlockRef}>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>



    ]);
}

export default Test;
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');



body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.fa-heart {
    color: rgb(256, 256, 256);
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    animation:  heartMove linear 1;
    top: -10vh;
    z-index: 0;
}

@keyframes heartMove {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(-10vh) ;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(110vh) ;
    }
}

#hearts-container {
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,pink,violet);
  inset: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.custom_btn {
    background-color: #FFB6C1;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

#noButton {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 150px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#yesButton {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 150px;
}
```

---

**Code snippet**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import photo from './somepng.png'

const Test = () => {

    const textBlockRef = useRef(null);
    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

    const openPopup = () => {
        setShowPopup(true);
    };

    const closePopup = () => {
        setShowPopup(false);
    };


    React.useEffect(() => {


        const body = document.querySelector("#hearts-container");

        const createHeart = () => {
            const heart = document.createElement("div");
            heart.className = "fas fa-heart";
            heart.style.left = `${Math.random() * 100}vw`;
            heart.style.animationDuration = `${Math.random() * 3 + 2}s`;
            body.appendChild(heart);
        };

        const removeOldHearts = () => {
            const heartArr = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-heart");
            if (heartArr.length > 200) {
                heartArr[0].remove();
            }
        };

        const heartInterval = setInterval(createHeart, 100);
        const removeInterval = setInterval(removeOldHearts, 100);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(heartInterval);
            clearInterval(removeInterval);
        };
    },
        []);

    return ([
        <div id="hearts-container"></div>,
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                <h1 className="header_text">Heading</h1>
                <div className="gif_container mt-3">
                    <img src={photo} alt="image" className="img-fluid" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={openPopup} style={{ marginTop: '40px' }}>Нажми на меня</button>
        </div>,
        <div className="text">
            
            {showPopup && (
                <div className="popup">
                    <div className="text_block" ref={textBlockRef}>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>



    ]);
}


ReactDOM.render(<Test />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');



body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.fa-heart {
    color: rgb(256, 256, 256);
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    animation:  heartMove linear 1;
    top: -10vh;
    z-index: 0;
}

@keyframes heartMove {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(-10vh) ;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(110vh) ;
    }
}

#hearts-container {
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,pink,violet);
  inset: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.custom_btn {
    background-color: #FFB6C1;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

#noButton {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 150px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#yesButton {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4f3ce16e3e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is the `height: 100vh;` property in the `body`.
What's happening is that you have set the height to exactly 100% of the viewport's height, so when you append the text, the total height of your elements is more than that in smaller viewports, and it breaks.

I don't know what you were trying to achieve by setting the body's height to 100vh, but I assume what you wanted to do was `min-height: 100vh`.

Comment: Unfortunately still the same :/. I change `height: 100vh;` to `min-height: 100vh` inside the `body`

Comment: If you want to create a code sandbox with your code I can have a look for you.